# Liquibase - Get Altered Row Count Output from SQL Changelog

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

I am wondering if there is a way to log the result output of insert/update/delete commands for example if I run the below, I would like to find the "1 row affected" output which I would otherwise see if I ran in SQL Server Management Studio.

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset tester:2
INSERT INTO liquibaseTest(id, description)
values (3, 'some really cool stuff')
```

Comment: what about changing [loglevel](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/advanced/loglevel.html)? Would that help?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried using loglevel.info but this did not output the information about the affected rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. This will also work to display count.
liquibase:update -X

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was not able to get this to work.  Getting below error when trying with -X

 `unexpected command parameters: [-X]`